# Produce data into Kafka topic with KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

The topic `test` already exists inside of a remote Kafka Cluster. The session details are saved in the `client` variable. We have three columns in our table called `FEATURE, ACCOUNTHOLDER, CLASS`.

Now I create `sample_table`.

```
client.create_table(table_name='sample_table',
                     columns_type=['FEATURE double', 'ACOUNTHOLDER string', 'CLASS int'],
                     topic='test',
                     value_format='DELIMITED',
                     key = 'ACCOUNTHOLDER')
```

The result is `true`. So the table is successfully created. 
Now I want to push data into `sample_table` by:

```
client.ksql("""INSERT INTO sample_table (FEATURE, ACCOUNTHOLDER, CLASS) VALUES (6.1, 'C1', 1)""")
```

I receive a NullPointerException.

```
KSQLError: ('java.lang.NullPointerException', 50000, ['io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.execution.InsertValuesExecutor.extractRow(InsertValuesExecutor.java:164)', 'io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.execution.InsertValuesExecutor.execute(InsertValuesExecutor.java:98)', 'io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.validation.CustomValidators.validate(CustomValidators.java:109)', 'io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.validation.RequestValidator.validate(RequestValidator.java:143)', 'io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.validation.RequestValidator.validate(RequestValidator.java:115)', 'io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.resources.KsqlResource.handleKsqlStatements(KsqlResource.java:163)', 'sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)', 'sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)', 'java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.serviceImpl(ServletContainer.java:409)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:584)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:525)', 'org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:462)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:174)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:753)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)', 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)', 'java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)'])
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you produce to the topic instead?

Comment: Is there an error in the ksql server log? And, as @cricket_007 says - can you edit your question to explain why you're using `INSERT` directly and not just produce data into the topic?